# How to find the output of convolutional_mlp of Theano tutorial based on python

Tags: output, convolution, theano, deep-learning

I have 10000 images fed to CNN in Theano tutorial described [here](https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials).

In the classification step, I want to classify those images into 40 classes. So, the number of units in the last layer would be 40. I want to get the predicted value from there. Layer3 calls 'LogisticRegression' function that is available in this package. I think CNN goes to   'LogisticRegression' function to evaluate the predicted values. How can I access to these value?
The info related to layers are:

```
 layer1 = LeNetConvPoolLayer(
    rng,
    input=layer0.output,
    image_shape=(batch_size, nkerns[0], 12, 12),
    filter_shape=(nkerns[1], nkerns[0], 5, 5),
    poolsize=(2, 2)
)

# the HiddenLayer being fully-connected, it operates on 2D matrices of
# shape (batch_size, num_pixels) (i.e matrix of rasterized images).
# This will generate a matrix of shape (batch_size, nkerns[1] * 4 * 4),
# or (500, 50 * 4 * 4) = (500, 800) with the default values.
layer2_input = layer1.output.flatten(2)

# construct a fully-connected sigmoidal layer
layer2 = HiddenLayer(
    rng,
    input=layer2_input,
    n_in=nkerns[1] * 4 * 4,
    n_out=500,
    activation=T.tanh
)

# classify the values of the fully-connected sigmoidal layer
layer3 = LogisticRegression(input=layer2.output, n_in=500, n_out=40)
```

I think, if we could get output from 'layer3', it would be great. I want this value, because I want to count how many samples in each class have been predicted accurately.
Is there any body to help

Comment: Which values would you like to access? Doesn't the tutorial specify how to create a function out of theano expressions to make selected expressions output their functional values given an input?

Comment: The program predicts the validation and test errors for classifying of 40 classes. What I want to get is to know about the predicted value of those classes. For example, I know that the actual label of  image 1. Now,  I want to know "what is the predicted of image 1".

Comment: Isn't that just `f = theano.function([input], layer3.output)` and then calling `f(new_image[np.newaxis])` ? (maybe `input` to be replaced by `layer0.input`)

Comment: Thank you again. How can I access to the parameters. for instance, layers?

Comment: f = theano.function([layer0.input], layer3.output)

NameError: name 'layer0' is not defined

Comment: You will have to post working code for me to help any further. I guessed `layer0`. Obviously, if it wasn't defined in your code, it won't work. You need to identify the input node and use that.

Comment: The code is [link] (https://github.com/lisa-lab/DeepLearningTutorials). I am working with _convolutional_mlp_ code, with the mnist dataset that is available in the data folder there. There is layer0 there, but it cannot be recognized when I call it.

Comment: NameError: name 'layer0_input' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with Theano but the reason you don't have access to layer0 is because when training the convolutional_mlp, you have to not only save layer3, you have to save all the layers. (Alternatively, you can choose to save the parameters from each layer and recreate them).

For example, in the while loop you can add the following:

```
with gzip.open('./testing/model.pkl.gz', 'w') as f:
    cPickle.dump([layer0_input, layer0, layer1, layer2_input, layer2, layer3], f)
```

Then you can do something like the following as a predict function.

```
  def predict(model='./testing/model.pkl.gz', 
            testset='./testing/testset.pkl.gz',
            batch_size=5):

      """ Load a trained model and use it to predict labels.

      :type model: Layers to accept inputs and produce outputs.
      """

      # Load the saved model.
      classifiers = cPickle.load(gzip.open(model))

      # Pick out the individual layer
      layer0_input = classifiers[0]
      layer0 = classifiers[1]
      layer1 = classifiers[2]
      layer2_input = classifiers[3]
      layer2 = classifiers[4]
      layer3 = classifiers[5]

      # Apply it to our test set
      testsets = load_data(testset)
      test_set_x = testsets.get_value()

      # compile a predictor function
      index = T.lscalar()

      predict_model = theano.function(
          [layer0_input],
          layer3.y_pred,
      )

      predicted_values = predict_model(
          test_set_x[:batch_size].reshape((batch_size, 1, 28, 23))
      )

      print('Prediction complete.')
      return predicted_values
```

The annoying thing is that by design of the tutorial, you have to pass in batches of the same size as you trained by. Here I only did one batch but you'd want to loop through all the batches in the test_set_x.